# Who is older, Michael or Lucifer?

Tags: supernatural

I was watching *Supernatural* [Season 11 Episode 18](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5539106/?ref_=ttep_ep18) where Darkness kind of kidnaps Lucifer, and she refers to Lucifer as God's most loved and his first Son. Now as far as I remember Michael is older than Lucifer right? In season 5 Michael told Dean that he practically raised Lucifer. So why did Darkness address Lucifer as God's first Son?

Answer (score 7):

### Michael is older

And indeed, from S05E22:

> MICHAEL:  No, you haven't changed a bit, little brother. Always blaming
>   everybody but yourself. We were together. We were happy. But you
>   betrayed me, all of us, and you made our Father leave.

The point of Dean being the ideal vessel for Michael, and Sam being the ideal vessel for Lucifer, **was precisely that their dynamic mirrored that between Michael and Lucifer.** Dean/Michael, the older son, obedient:

> MICHAEL: I'm sorry. I can't do that. I'm a good son. I have orders.

And the younger son, the favorite, who doesn't want to do what his father tells him to: Sam/Lucifer.

Similarly, Cain was older than Abel, which is probably why Dean was given the Mark of Cain. This dynamic, of father, younger brother, older brother, is central to the series.

From S11E18:

> AMARA: As God's favorite, his first son, you may be the one thing in all of
>   creation that he still cares about, the one thing that could finally
>   make him show himself so that I can confront him and he can
>   acknowledge the wrongs he's done me. And then he can witness the utter
>   destruction of all his creation before he himself is swept away.

It seems that the best way to interpret "first son" is as "first in God's affections," which is supported by its coming after "favorite." Because otherwise, it would mean that not only did the writers change their mind about who was older, but forgot about *the whole reason for Michael being older in the first place*.

Answer (score 0):

Michael is the older one, as he said himself in *The Song Remains The Same*:

Later on in *Swan Song*, Michael called Lucifer "little brother":

Michael and Lucifer's story parallels that of Dean and Sam, with both Michael and Dean being the older brother who follows the brothers' father's orders, while both Lucifer and Sam being the younger brother who's rebellious to their father, as Gabriel stated in *Changing Channels*:

The Darkness referring to Lucifer as God's first son in season 11 was an error. They later corrected it. The in-universe reason is probably that the Darkness had been sealed for billions of years so she didn't get her information right.

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking from the show, Lucifer is the younger brother. To maintain the parallels in the show, this worked. However, Lucifer was God's first creation and nearly perfect. He was the Morningstar and given free will. According to the mythology, God thought Lucifer to be pure up until an hour before he fell. Finding that free will was detrimental to order in heaven and fearing a possible uprising, God stripped the rest of the angels of their free will. Long story short, Lucifer is not only older, but first of everything.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. So you mean to say that in the show the order of Michael and Lucifer is depicted wrong? In actuality Lucifer is older than Michael?

Answer (score -2):

Lucifer was actually the first, but I think spn changed it to match with sam and dean.  Micheal and Dean the older boy following orders, and Sam and Lucifer being rebellious and yada yada

Comment: Can you provide any evidence?

Answer (score -3):

My interpretation is that Lucifer was Chuck's first creation, a beautiful youth. Michael was created later as a full-blown warrior, a ready-made 'older brother'.

Comment: Interpretation based on what exactly?